# Do we say "His pants are holed in several places" & "his pants are split open at the back"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

> [split](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/split_1?q=split) [intransitive, transitive] to tear, or to make something tear,
>   along a straight line
>
> Her dress had split along the seam.
>
> **split something** Don't tell me you've split another pair of pants!
>
> **split open** The cushion split open and sent feathers everywhere.
>
> **split something open** He split the packet open and poured out a
>   handful of peanuts.

---

> [hole](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hole_2) [transitive, usually passive] to make a hole or holes in
>   something, especially a boat or ship
>
> **be holed by something** The ship had been holed by a missile.
>
> **be holed** The hull was holed in several places.

Some poor children in developing countries often wear clothes that "**are holed or split open**" because they don't have money to buy new ones, **not because of the fashion style**.

**What would you say if you saw these pictures?**

Do we say "**His jeans are holed in several places**" & "**his pants are split open at the back**"?

[image]

[image]

Comment: *His pants/ trousers are in holes or tattered*.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul, but sometimes, there is only one hole on the pants, would we still say "The pants are in holes" or "the pants are in A hole"?

Comment: I've never had a pair of trousers having *one hole*. You might as well call it 'tattered' or 'in hole'... I don't know.

Comment: A _split_ in a garment is usually caused by the fabric tearing apart where it is stretched in a place where the body bends, such as the knee or seat (as in the lower picture). The hole in the jeans is not in a place like that; the wearer probably caught their jeans on something sharp. I'd say they have a _hole_ or _tear_ in them

Comment: @KateBunting, why not "they have a hole ON them"? why "IN"?

Comment: Because that is how we say it! I suppose the tear is _in_ the weave of the fabric, it's not something applied from outside like a patch or a spot of paint.